# Synchronizing internal variables and widgets' values

Tags: c++, qt

Situation:

There is a QGLWidget, which visualizes my data. There are also many variables to control parameters of the visualization. The user can change values of the variables by interacting with multiple QWidgets on the form, thus, affecting visualization methods. QWidgets are connected with variables by means of SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism. Important is that every SLOT ends up with update (rerendering) on QGLWidget.

Problems:

1. When the user loads a file with settings, where a set of parameters is stored, the states of (multiple) QWidgets are changed together with values of the variables. This leads to multiple updates (re-renderings) of the QGLWidget. First, this is unnecessary as only one last update would suffice. Second, it slows down the program as the rendering step is expensive.
2. Same problem occurs on program start, when initial values of variables should be synchronized with QWidgets current states.

Does anybody have a solution to the problems above?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to block signals on loading data like this:

```
void MainWindow::loadSettings(Settings *settings)
{
    foreach (QWidget *w, settingsWidgets)
    {
        w->blockSignals(true);
        w->loadSettings(settings);
        w->blockSignals(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: should it be w->blockSignls(false) after setting?